# Automatically increment an excel cell value periodically

Tags: excel

Let's say cell A1 has the value 1. I want this cell to increment itself every second.
So after 1 second, cell A1 now has the value 2. After two seconds the value is 3, etc, etc, etc.

How can I set that up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to do it using VBA:

```
Sub CellTimer()

    Sheet1.Range("A2").Value = 1
    Do
        Application.Wait (Now() + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
        Sheet1.Range("A2").Value = Sheet1.Range("A2").Value + 1
    Loop

End Sub
```

This has its quirks, but I don't know what you're going to use this for, so I don't know, maybe this will suit your purposes.

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, what quirks are involved in this exactly?

Comment: Each iteration will take not 1 second, but 1 second plus the execution time for the code in the `Do...Loop` (right now this is tiny, but will grow if you put more code in there). My example can be rewritten to eliminate this effect, if you're concerned. Is it worth it? That's up to you. Also, `.Wait` won't let you do anything while it's waiting.

Answer (score 2):

You could use this:

```
=ROUND(NOW()*24*3600,0)-3522649665
```

where `3522649665` is just an arbitrary offset. You may have to force a recalculation using <kbd>F9</kbd> or the VBA command `Sheet1.Range("A1").Calculate` (assuming you put the formula in cell A1).

Comment: Thanks, this works exactly for what I need... which is just finding out if I can do it. I'm just experimenting so I really appreciate your input into my education ;)

Answer (score 0):

This works for me for recalculating every second:

```
Sub CalculateNow()
    'Your code here
    'i.e.
    Calculate 'This recalculates all your cell values


    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"), "CalculateNow"
End Sub
```